# Cannot send emails via Yahoo SMTP

Tags: php

I am trying to use Yahoo SMTP server to send emails from a web site, located on local Windows server and based on Xampp.

As a result, this is what I have in my sendmail settings :

```
smtp_server=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=box1@yahoo.com
auth_password=pswd1
```

Then in PHP :

```
mail ('box1@yahoo.com', 'Static Mail 1', 'Static Message');
mail ('box2@yahoo.com', 'Static Mail 2', 'Static Message');
```

So, I am trying to send email from one Yahoo account to another but it does not work.
I tried to send emails with GMail SMTP and it works fine but when I try to do this through Yahoo SMTP I always get an error :

```
From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html
```

As far as I know, this is a common problem when Yahoo does not allow to send emails on behalf of it, but in my case I am sending messages only between Yahoo accounts, what am I doing wrong?

Issue for cross server requests is described [here](http://yahoomail.tumblr.com/post/82426900353/yahoo-dmarc-policy-change-what-should-senders) but in some reason I am experiencing it even when I use only Yahoo accounts too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error is pretty self explanatory, add the fourth paramater for the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, something like this:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```